# Resistance of a fully conected graph?

Tags: resistance, graph

How would one approach to solving for the resistance between any two nodes of a fully connected graph with an arbitrary number of nodes n and arbitrary resistance between them ? (resistors omitted from image for clarity)

[image: Fully connected graph with R_{i,j} resistance in between nodes]

Comment: This seem to me as a purely theoretical exercise having a little value in a real-life problems.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Or even worse: homework with no solution attempt.

Comment: This makes it worth less ? On the contrary.

Comment: Numerically. With a computer.

Comment: Yes. It is asking us to develop a theory (too broad) about non-engineering problem (off-topic).

Comment: @JackB I am pretty sure there is a general analytical solution.

Comment: Agreed. It's not worthless. It applies to numerical approaches that solve for the resistance between two points on a sheet or along the edges of a sheet. So are you looking for a numerical software approach that is iterative or looking for closed solutions that solve directly through symbolic manipulation? Are the connecting edges all the same resistance or may they each be different? What are you allowing to vary? What remains constant? A very simple software approach to the above would use a checkboard solving approach, which I've used for e-fields near arbitrary metal shapes.

Comment: @EugeneSh. With an arbitrary number of nodes and arbitrary resistances? Surely you could then choose the resistances to make it very hard to solve analytically. And there are many, many possible choices of resistances...

Comment: I would prefer an analytic solution or at least some pointers. I agree with some of the comments and will provide analytic solution for up to n=3 or 4. Maybe this motivates a solution by induction.

Comment: @JackB I don't have the solution in my hands, but I would imagine some kind of matrix equation, where the number of nodes is just the matrix dimension.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Drifting away from the topic a bit, but if you choose n large and then the resistances to be variously R or large, you can get the problem in this comic https://xkcd.com/356/.  Which I know to be fairly hard.

Comment: Do 2 nodes, then 3 ... etc and see if a pattern emerges.

Comment: It is a much simpler problem though if all of the resistances are the same as each other.  Maybe that's what @userčina meant?

Comment: Chu, this is what I ment with induction. Of course I  would prefer a more general case when all resistencese are arbitrary, but I guess if that fails equal resistance is the next best thing. In that setting every resistance varies. My hope is to find a mathematical problem which coresponds to this schematics and for which the solution could be just measured instead of computed.

Comment: Are we assuming that between each two nodes there is a resistor and all resistors are the same value or different value resistors?

Answer (score 3):

**The equal-resistance case**

In the case where all resistances are equal (call it \$R\$), the solution is straightforward. Without loss of generality we can label the two nodes we are measuring between as node 1 and node 2.  We consider a voltage applied between the two nodes. We can re-draw the graph with the entry and exit nodes separate, and the others in a line:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1y8W5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here I have omitted many resistors which joins nodes 3 to n with each other.  However, by symmetry, it should be obvious that nodes 3 to n are all at the same potential, so no current flows between them and the resistors joining them are irrelevant.  It should now be obvious that the resistance between Node 0 and Node 1 is the parallel combination of R and N-2 instances of two resistors in series.  Thus the total resistance is:

\$R_{1,2} = \left(\frac{1}{R} + \frac{(n-2)}{2R}\right)^{-1} = \frac{2R}{n}\$

**The arbitrary resistance case**

There is (as far as I know) no simple solution.  You must assume some voltage between the nodes of interest, and then write down ohms law for each resistor in the graph, and current conservation equations for each node.  For a graph with \$n\$ nodes, you will get \$n\$ current conservation equations, and \$n^2\$ resistance equations. You now have \$n^2+n\$ equations, and the \$n^2+n-1\$ unknowns, so you can solve the system of linear equations. This may be quite time consuming.

Answer (score 0):

Node voltage analysis? Make an equation for each node such that all the currents flowing in total 0. Solve the set of simultaneous linear equations.

Comment: Times number of nodes...

Comment: I'm not sure what you're driving at. There would, of course, be an equation for each node, and there would be an unknown for each node voltage appearing in every equation. It _would_ be time consuming to solve manually. That's what computers are for. The method is straightforward. My answer leads off with a question, because I didn't know why there weren't similar answers. What's the problem with using the node voltage method?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there can be single general analytical solution.  With n nodes, you'll have either n/2 or (n-1)/2 possible resistances depending on symmetry which forms a discontinuous solution. So you'd have at the very least two sets of equations for odd and even numbers of nodes.  More as you navigate the periphery. And that's for all resistances being equal.  If the resistances are arbitrary, the number of discontinuities increases for each different resistance.  This makes the whole thing totally unwieldy.

The best approach is to consider all resistance equal and use a numeric simulation.  It's fairly easy then.

1. Simulate 4 nodes with your favourite simulator.
2. Ground node 0.
3. Apply voltage to each node in turn going around the periphery till hitting the symmetric point, dependant on evenness. So for n = 4, measure current n01 and n02.
4. Calculate equivalent resistance.
5. Plot total nx along x axis.
6. Plot resistance along y axis.
7. Numerically fit a curve to the results for n = 4.
8. Loop and repeat for all 4 < n < 16. I think for n > 15 results will become asymptotic.
9. Colour graph to taste.

So you'll have 12 curves. You might also be able to convert this graph to 3D, but obviously you wouldn't be able to form a continuous surface. This is your best way forward.  You can see that this is all cumbersome.  Now imagine this extended for multiple arbitrary resistances.  You wouldn't be able to stop at n = 15 either.  Your original exercise becomes infeasible.

PS.  I've excluded n = 2 as trivial, and n = 3 as atypical as there are no resistors passing though the interior of the hull.